# How to solve a q-shift difference equation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

How to solve the q-shift difference equation $W(x)=(x-a)W(xq^{-2})$? Here $W(x)$ is the unknown function. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried using that equation like a fixed-point equation, iterating and trying to see if the process converges?

Comment: @Mariano, the process will run forever.

Comment: That is *exactly* why I suggested to see of the process converges. I very much doubt there is a solution to the equation in finite terms!

Comment: @Mariano, but in the difference case, $W(x)=(x-a)W(x+h)$, the solution is a $\Gamma$ function. If we iterate, the process is also run forever.

Comment: Do ypu understand what 'see if the process converges' means?

Comment: @Mariano, my understanding is $W(x)=(x-a)(xq^{-2}-a)(xq^{-4}-a)\cdots (xq^{-2n})W(xq^{n-1})$ and we can know $W(xq^{n-1})$ for some $n$. Maybe this is not what you mean 'the process converges'.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. You should review —in a calculus book— the properties of infinite products (it usually comes right after those of infinite series). The little book by Knopp titled *Theory and application of infinite series* is a great source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $a\neq 0$ and $q>1$.  We can define $G(u) = a^{-u} f(u) W(q^{2u})$, where $f(u)$ is a function satisfying $f(u+1)=-f(u)$.  Then
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
G(u) &=& a^{-u}f(u)W(q^{2u}) \\ &=& a^{-u}f(u)(q^{2u} - a)W(q^{2u}q^{-2}) \\ &=& a^{-(u-1)}f(u-1)(1-a^{-1}q^{2u}) W(q^{2(u-1)}) \\ &=& (1-a^{-1}q^{2u})G(u-1).
\end{eqnarray}
$$
This gives $G(u)$ as a convergent infinite product times a scale factor (equal to $\lim_{u\rightarrow-\infty}G(u)$), which we will take to be $1$:
$$
G(u) = (1-a^{-1}q^{2u})(1-a^{-1}q^{2(u-1)})\cdots = (a^{-1}q^{2u};q^{-2})_{\infty},
$$
where $(\alpha;\beta)_\infty$ is the [q-Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol).  Now, taking $x=q^{2u}$, we can invert this to obtain
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
W(x) = \frac{a^{u}}{f(u)}\left(\frac{x}{a};q^{-2}\right)_{\infty}=e^{(i\pi+\ln a)u}\left(\frac{x}{a};q^{-2}\right)_{\infty},
\end{eqnarray}
$$
choosing $f(u)=e^{-i\pi u}$,
or
$$
W(x) = \exp\left({\frac{i\pi + \ln a}{2 \ln q}\cdot\ln x}\right)\left(\frac{x}{a};q^{-2}\right)_{\infty}.
$$
This is a particular solution, given by a particular choice of $f$.  To obtain the *general* solution, multiply $W(x)$ by any function of $u=\ln x / (2 \ln q)$ that is periodic with period $1$.

Comment: thank you very much. Why do you know how to define $G(u)$ to solve this problem?

Comment: The change of variable $x=q^{2u}$ turns the multiplicative shift into an additive shift.  You then have an infinite-looking product, but its terms approach $(-a)$ instead of $1$ (which they need to approach for the product to converge).  Factoring out the $(-a)$, in the form of $a^{-u}f(u)$, leaves the remaining product convergent.